# How to check if an app has an access to Direct Messages?

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-rest-api

I'm aware that access is returned as `X-Access-Level` header in response to API requests. But I noticed `read-write` is returned for both `Read and Write` and `Read, Write and Direct Messages`. So, how do I know if the app has access to `Direct Messages` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with the [Apigee Twitter console](https://apigee.com/console/twitter) I get `x-access-level:
read-write-directmessages` as a response header. The access token granted for the account you are testing likely doesn't have DM access granted. Try revoking the access token and authorizing it again.